# Django: Adding a confirmation dialog box after pressing the 'save' button in change_form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-admin

I would like to run a backend code after pressing the 'Save' button in the change_form (admin) screen, which will be followed by a confirmation dialog box which will ask something like 'nothing found, create new entity anyway?'
By pressing 'ok' in the dialog box the application will continue with the normal 'save' functionality. Pressing the 'cancel' button will throw us back to the change_form screen.

The workflow i'm trying to achieve is:
Press 'save' > run a python validation code > if code returns 'false' continue with the original 'save' functionality, else popup a dialog box > [dialog box] Ok > save the entity, cancel > stay on the change_form page.

Thanks for the help

Comment: I tried to find the original python/template files which are connected to the 'save' button functionality, Unforunately it wasn't that easy to follow the code.

Answer (score 1):

Add a listener on the submit button with jQuery. Then fire off an Ajax request to the server to see if something has been found or not. Then display the dialog accordingly.

Comment: This what you would usually do, but where is the submit button located? I couldn't find it since Django is based on a large set of templates. Thanks

Comment: It's in the change_form.html template. It's a template tag or a variable if I remember correctly. But that doesn't matter. You can override it with jQuery using its id.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for something similar, to show a confirmation popup before updating some values and I found a library [django-admin-confirm](https://github.com/TrangPham/django-admin-confirm) posting here for future explorers.